# why does it give nan after i give a input 8 and 66176

Tags: c++, double, nan

i am getting the output nan whereas several other smaller test cases gave the correct output but not this one

```
#include<iostream>
#include<cmath>
#include<iomanip>
using namespace std;

int main(){
    //m => no of faces n => no of time it is rolled
    int m = 8;
    int n = 66716;
    long double summed;
    int i = 1;
    while (i <= m){
        summed += ((pow(i,n)-pow(i-1,n))/pow(m,n))*i;
        i += 1;
    }
    cout << fixed << setprecision(6) << summed;
    return 0;
}
```

expected output 8.00000

but output is nan

Comment: Because here `pow(m,n))` you're calculating the 66176th power of 8. Try something smaller or use a bignum library.

Comment: your summed variable is not initialized. so it contains garbage

Comment: Blaze, phon thnx , i think i need bignum library

Comment: When you write a test case for specific values, like this one, just initialize the variables with those values. Don't make readers go through figuring out what the input should be.

Comment: pete you are right i should have done that